# How to use partitive articles following possessive adjectives?

Tags: grammaire, articles, possessif, partitif

For instance, how would I translate the following sentence?

> Where is my water?

And I mean specifically using *eau*, not cheating by using *mon verre*. Would it be *Où est mon eau?* or *Où est mon d'eau?*

Comment: **comments deleted** please move discussions that are not aimed at improving the question to the [chat].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Où est mon eau?

Would be the correct translation here.

You seem to have trouble with *d'* here. Let me clarify:

> *Mon verre d'eau ~= Mon verre **de** eau* as in *Mon verre **de** lait*

This is the actual way to read it, but you always contract the *de* if you can. It's the same as *My glass **of** water*. In English you wouldn't say *Where is my of water*, right?

Comment: I am uncertain what indicates that I am having trouble with when to contract *d'* or what it means . . . just wasn't positive whether I needed a partitive article after a possessive!

Comment: @Aerovistae Sorry if I assumed that; *de, du, d', de la* are usually the root of many problems in French, hence I thought you had problem understanding what it meant. Because this was an exemple that translates itself word to word (*Où est mon d'eau = Where is my of water*) which you would never say in English.

Comment: Thanks :) I understand now; I suspected that was the case.

Comment: @Aerovistae If this answer solved your issue, don't forget to mark it as accepted. This removes the question from the *Unanswered* category.