# Indefinite article with possessive adjective

Tags: grammaire, articles, possessif

In the [expression](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23852/why-de-in-de-vos-nouvelles)

> C'est bon d'avoir de vos nouvelles !

we need the indefinite article *de* because "vos nouvelles" is indefinite in this sentence. (We don't know which news are mentioned.)

What are some other examples of this construction? When is it used? I don't usually see

> C'est du mon riz.

or

> Ce sont de vos chaises.

Comment: It's the use of *de* that makes *vos nouvelles*  indefinite. You might find [this post](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11570/358) about the various uses of *de* interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*<strike>C'est du mon riz</strike>* is impossible because it would be using two consecutive definite determiners:
- *le*, article and definite determiner contained in the partitive article *du* (→ de+le) and
- *vos* which is a possessive definite determiner.

But one could have:

> C'est de mon riz.

and

> Ce sont de vos chaises.

where *de* is followed by just one determiner.

Having *de* in front of the determiner indicates that you designate a certain amount, not all your chairs, my rice, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain the difference between "Ce sont **de** vos chaises" and "Ce sont vos chaises" (and similarly with "riz")? It is still not clear to me.